# Poor Performance Sqlite.net extensions

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

Hi I am developing a Xamarin app that load lots of lines ( around 10K )

I got really poor performance something like 2 minutes to insert 5K lines of an object.

I use InsertOrReplaceWithChildren:

```
 public  bool Insert_Update_Many<T>(List<T> obj)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (this.Lock) {
                _connection.RunInTransaction(() => {
                    _connection.InsertOrReplaceAllWithChildren(obj, true);
                });
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("[SQLITE_ERROR]: " + ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Since I add "RunInTransaction" I got an improvement (before it was 5 min+).

My objects contains relations ships.

Is there any way to optimize that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the actual code, but I faced few issues that may affect performance:

- **`InsertOrReplace` performance is bad**: Try calling simple `Insert` statements instead of `InsertOrReplace`. In some scenarios this may have a big impact.
- **SQLite.Net performs insert operations one by one**: this one complex to workaround, as it requires you to write insert queries manually to perform more than one insert on each statement.
- **SQLite-Net Extensions performs `update` operations after insert**: this is simple to workaround, you can assign foreign keys by yourself and call plain SQLite.Net `Insert` on database intensive operations.

Comment: I think you right I have to re write my logic for my scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You can improve insert performance by using [WAL](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) mode:

```
 var journalMode = await globalConn.ExecuteScalarAsync<string>("PRAGMA journal_mode = wal");
```

Comment: It improves a little but not significantly :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion:

Try with raw queries, or actually, first profile the code, maybe there's a bottleneck somewhere in there.

And if you get nothing, I guess you'll just have to do it async and have user wait (**or ship the database file with your app**)

Comment: I did and the problem is in the insert... When I use none sqlite extensions method it is actually fast but I lost the advantages of the extensions. shipping the database with the app is not an option as the data are set on a back office and modify many time